# Customised string in spark scala

Tags: scala

I have a string like `"debug#compile"`. Now, my end goal is to convert first letter of each word to uppercase. So, at last I should get `"Debug#Compile"` where `'D'` and `'C'` are converted to uppercase.

My logic:
1) I have to split the string on the basis of delimiters. It will be special characters.So, I have to check everytime.
2) After that I would convert each word's first letter to upper case and then using map I would join it again.

I am trying my best but not able to design the code for this. Can anyone help me in this. Even **hints** would help!

Below is my code:

```
object WordCase {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val s="siddhesh#kalgaonkar"
    var b=""
    val delimeters= Array("#","_")


      if(delimeters(0)=="#")
      {
         b=s.split(delimeters(0).toString).map(_.capitalize).mkString(delimeters(0).toString())
      }
      else if(delimeters(0)=="_")
      {
        b=s.split(delimeters(0).toString).map(_.capitalize).mkString(delimeters(0).toString())
      }
      else{
        println("Non-Standard String")
      }


    println(b)
  }
}
```

My code capitalizes the first letter of every word in capital on the basis of constant delimeter and have to merge it. Here for the first part i.e `"#"` it capitalizes first letter of every words but it fails for the second case i.e `"_"`. Am I makinig any silly mistakes in looping?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic ? you can pass the delimiter as parameter.

Comment: how this code related to Spark ? and where are you getting this String in column value or as a variable ?

Comment: By dynamic, you mean working spark column?

Comment: can you provide more details , what should be expected output for your input "siddhesh#kalgaonkar" and what you mean by dynamic?

Comment: I have provided the output in the second line itself, Nikk. Also, I am very close. could you please help me . I have described in the question

Comment: `if(delimeters(0)=="#")` is always true

Comment: Nop. For the second case also I am getting the output but not as expected

Comment: How to getting non alphanumeric character from a string? That would solve my problem definitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the easy way:

```
object WordCase {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val s = "siddhesh_kalgaonkar"


    var b = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ").split(" ").map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ") //Replacing delimiters with space and capitalizing first letter of each word
    val c=b.indexOf(" ") //Getting index of space
    val d=s.charAt(c).toString // Getting delimiter character from the original string 
    val output=b.replace(" ", d) //Now replacing space with the delimiter character in the modified string i.e 'b'
    println(output)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val s="siddhesh#kalgaonkar"

scala> val specialChar = (s.split("[a-zA-Z0-9]") filterNot Seq("").contains).mkString

scala> s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+"," ").split(" ").map(_.capitalize).mkString(",").replaceAll(",",specialChar)
res41: String = Siddhesh#Kalgaonkar
```

You can manage multiple special char in this way

```
scala> val s="siddhesh_kalgaonkar"
s: String = siddhesh_kalgaonkar

scala> val specialChar = (s.split("[a-zA-Z0-9]") filterNot Seq("").contains).mkString
specialChar: String = _

scala> s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+"," ").split(" ").map(_.capitalize).mkString(",").replaceAll(",",specialChar)
res42: String = Siddhesh_Kalgaonkar
```

Comment: Tried this one but in mkString() I have to pass the delimeter as well. I can't skip it.

Comment: if you not want to consider digit as a special char then you can also add it in regex like [^a-zA-Z0-9] instead of [^a-zA-Z]

Comment: means you want output like Siddhesh#Kalgaonkar?

Comment: Suppose I have special characters like "#, _" so while creating the string again I need it back in the middle. So, could you please modify your code accordingly?

Comment: Yeah, you understood my problem finally!

Comment: check it now, this will work if you have single special char in String

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for your efforts, @Nikk. I solved it the easy way. So, I answered my own question. Could you please upvote my question. I don't know why people downvote the question instead of helping

Comment: Great.. could you please mark my answer as resolver.